# Spring Cloud (Netflix OSS) Vs WSO2

Tags: java, wso2, microservices, spring-cloud

With the goal of building multiple microservices that are fault tolerant and resilient:

Microservices are currently being built using Spring Boot

What are the key differences between WSO2 API Manager and Spring Cloud ?

Using different components of Spring Cloud can one build a comparable solution akin to WSO2 API manager or general API manger ? If so what would be the components of Spring Cloud one could use ?

Can one mix and match components of Spring Cloud with WSO2 API manager ? How compatible is WSO2 API manager with Spring Cloud ?

For example: Use the load balancer(Ribbon) and Service Discovery(Eureka) of Spring Cloud and then also use Security and the analytic components of WS02